# (XForms) Select node in nodeset repeater automatically by clicking a button

Tags: xml, xforms, xforms-betterform

I use XForms with betterFORM to realize forms in an HTML document.
I implemented a nodeset repeater in a table. Now I want to realize that there is automatically selected a particular node in this repeat table by clicking a button. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`setindex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#action-setindex) action allows you to "mark a specific item as current in a repeating sequence". You can run it upon form load for example with:

```
<xf:setindex
    ev:event="xforms-ready"
    repeat="my-repeat"
    index="2"/>
```